# Running main class in test directory

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

I have a very basic gradle project, and have a test file with main().  The file - "src/test/javaTestRunner.java" is as follows:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

The code compiles ("./gradlew classes" and "./gradlew testclasses" works fine).  However, I am not able to execute TestRunner, not able to find the correct way to invoke the above class.  I have tried the following:

./gradlew test --tests TestRunner
./gradlew test TestRunner
./gradlew TestRunner

"build.gradle" contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'MyFirstJavaProgram'
```

Any suggestions.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: why you want to create a Test Runner, instead of just running the tests directly

Comment: I am just following a tutorial and trying to following the tutorial.  The tutorial does everything on command line (even javac).  I prefer to use build system, and choose intellij.

Comment: In that case do not bother with test runner. just write your test classes in src/test/java.../TestSomething.java with @Test annotation and then simply run ./gradlew test

Comment: gradle junit test runner will pickup all the tests and execute for you

Comment: and in intellij you can simple code the test and execute the same. You will see a green arrow button next to every test method in intellij idea, just click that to execute one test.

Comment: @gagansingh  Thank you for the info.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A alternate way of running the main method as a gradle test:
Change the main method to a non-static method with no parameters and annotated  with `@Test`:

```java
public class TestRunner {

    @Test
    public void runTests() {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) { // consider using assertAll (JUnit5)
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful()); // consider using assertTrue (JUnit5)
    }
}
```

Then `./gradlew test --tests TestRunner` should now work.

Nice JUnit 5 tutorial [Writing Tests with JUnit 5](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/09/writing-tests-with-junit-5/) by Trisha Gee of JetBrains.